# How we can get data from Website using Webbot

Tags: python, selenium, webbot

Trying Web.find_elements but it is throwing an error

> **AttributeError: 'Browser' object has no attribute 'find_elements'**

**Code**

```
from webbot import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
web = Browser()
web.go_to('http://some_link')
web.click(id='link_continue')
print("Login Successful")
web.type('some_value' , into = 'Enter your product name, UPC, EAN, ISBN or ASIN')
web.click(id='a-autoid-0')
web.type('799',tag='input',id='afn-pricing')
web.type('923',tag='input',id='afn-cost-of-goods')
web.click(id='update-fees-link')
web.find_elements(id="afn-selling-fees")[0].get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: If you're using selenium you're probably looking for `find_element_by_id`, see [docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html); if you're using something else give more details.

Comment: am using webbot

Comment: What versions (Python, webbot) are you using?

Comment: Python - 3.4.4 and webbot - 0.0.9

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're seeing is due to using an old version of webbot; upgrade to the latest version (`0.1.4`).

`find_elements` was added in [Dec 2018](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/webbot/commit/2a1ea1a835ed4ac2b13e023748d4d07169d561de)
but your version (`0.0.9`) is from [Jul 2018](https://pypi.org/project/webbot/#history)

Comment: Thanks @Ionut Ticus for the quick response, it worked after webbot upgrade.. One more question how i can extract 62.07 value from `<div class="hiddenBox" id="afn-selling-fees">62.07</div>`

Comment: You can probably access the underlying Selenium object and use that (`web.driver`).

Answer (score 0):

Got the value using text in place of get_attribute('outerHTML')

`web.find_elements(id="afn-selling-fees")[0].text`